# Finding chromatic polynomial for v=9 E= 15

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a graph that Im working with to find its chromatic polynomial. I have managed smaler ones but this have me scratching my head a bit. It's defined as a cycle {1,2}{2,3}....{8,9}{9,1} with six extra edges: {9,7}{1,7}{1,6}{6,9}{1,4}{1,3}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ghh.png

My problem is two fold. First, should just try to walk through the graph or should I use the decomposition theorem? I feel like I should be able to do it with out the theorem but I can't realy tell. Also, are there any good rule for what edge to delet/merge?

Secondly. When I do try to figure it out, Im a bit confused as how to handle the branching.

I started out coloring v1 and going on like this:

X(X-1)(X-2) for 1,2 and 3. Now I could go to 5 and split that up into,

1. Same as 1
2. Same as 3
3. Not same as 1 nor 3

Then again, 4 cant be the same as either 1 or 3 so it has to be (x-2) and then 5 can be whatever color 4 isnt so shouldnt that just be (X-1)?

The anser is X(X-1)(x-2)^4(X-3)(X^2-3x+3) and I got  close on one run. That just makes it worse though, as soon as I start branching I get the feeling that its arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this, for me, is to look for complete graphs:

If you start at vertex 8 you can see that it is adjacent to only 7 and 9 and so is in a triangle, $K_3$.
Now, 1,6,7 and 9 form a $K_4$, so we have to use all different colours for that.

Similarly, 123 is a triangle and then so is 134, and this leaves 1456 which is a $C_4$.

Rebuilding all of this together you get $x(x-1)(x^2-3x+3)$ for the $C_4$ then two factors of $(x-2)$ from vertices 2 and 3. Then 7 and 9 give us a factor of $(x-2)(x-3)$ (since they have to be different from each other and from that of vertices 1 and 7. Finally, vertex 8 has $(x-2)$ choices for it, giving the answer you are looking for.

As general advice for these kinds of problems, the best idea is to search for "complete intersections" as outlined in my notes [here](http://faculty.capebretonu.ca/jpreen/math415.pdf) (on the bottom of page 24), the simplest versions of this theorem are cut-vertices and pairs of vertices joined by an edge which are a cutset, as in your graph.

Comment: (Not related to the answer) I just moved to Dalhousie Uni, also in Nova Scotia.  By any chance, are you going to CanaDAM or going to planning to visit Dalhousie?  We should catch up if you are.

Comment: hi @Douglas S. Stones, hoping to meet you at CanaDAM. I didn't think I was going to be able to make it, but can, now, hopefully...